# Best way to save an array of complex numbers with HDF5 and C

Tags: c, arrays, hdf5, complex-numbers

What is the recommended way to save an array of complex numbers with HDF5 and C in terms of performance and ease of use? I need to save a very large array of complex numbers and my users will read the file with C, Python, or Matlab.

I was reading in [this post](http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/Complex-numbers-td2064099.html) a suggestion to save them as a compound data type. I also read some suggestions on using two separate arrays, one for real numbers and one for imaginary numbers.

**Edit 1:**

I decided to use the example suggested in the comments:

```
  Typedef struct {
     double re;   /*real part */
     double im;   /*imaginary part */
  } complex_t;

  complex_t tmp;  /*used only to compute offsets */
  hid_t complex_id = H5Tcreate (H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof tmp);
  H5Tinsert (complex_id, "real", HOFFSET(tmp,re),
            H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
  H5Tinsert (complex_id, "imaginary", HOFFSET(tmp,im),
            H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE);
```

Comment: The HDF documentation contains an example of defining a compound data type for complex numbers.  See  http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/UG_frame04ProgModel.html If that's not to your taste you had better explain much more clearly your requirements and any evidence you have for preferring one approach or another.  As it stands your question might be ruled off-topic on the grounds that it invites opinion-based answers.  What do you mean by *best* ?  What would it take to convince you ?

Comment: Link is dead. Should probably be https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/03_Model.html